# Temperature coefficient of diode

Tags: diodes

Diode voltage changes with temperature according to the Shockley diode equation.

I understand this , but what I don't understand is why diodes have a negative temperature coefficient (why voltage decreases with temperature.)

The temperature (T) is in the numerator of the equation so it should increase.

[image: diode voltage equation]

Comment: Is is an exponential function of temperature.

Comment: Is has some dependence in temperature but it have little effect in Vd , Not effective as the Term "T" in this equstion

Comment: @isam What you are missing in that equation is the temperature dependence of \$I_\text{S}\$. It's huge. So large in fact, that it changes the sign. See [my writing here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330588/a-confusion-about-the-formula-for-transistor-vbe-ic-characterisitcs/330612#330612). The approximate equation looks like this: $$I_S\left(T\right)=I_{S_{T_{nom}}}\cdot\left[\left(\frac{T}{T_{nom}}\right)^{3}e^{\frac{E_g}{k}\cdot\frac{T-T_{nom}}{T\cdot T_{nom}}}\right]$$ The power of 3 is approximate and is sometimes treated as an "adjustable" parameter. But close.

Comment: @jonk well that change a lot , this is the first time i see this equation , most articles i read just write schockley equation alone , it looks like a lot of physics is involved so they stay floating

Comment: I think my link provides references. But you are right. It's in more esoteric published papers where you find these details. You asked a good question. I'll have to +1 for that.

Comment: @jonk can you repost your answer here to select it as my answer, and for the future visitor also

Comment: @isam Done. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Preceding the question

As I'm sure you can find repeated in many places, the simple Shockley diode equation is:

$$I_\text{D}=I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}\left(e^\frac{V_\text{D}}{\eta \:V_T}-1\right), \text{where }V_T=\frac{k\: T}{q}$$

The emission coefficient, \$\eta\$, is usually taken to be 1, by default. The saturation current \$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}\$ is effectively a \$y\$-axis intercept point found by projecting the log-chart plot of diode current vs diode voltage. The -1 term in the equation removes this *offset* and brings the results into expectation where the diode voltage is \$0\:\text{V}\$.

Solving for \$V_\text{D}\$:

$$V_\text{D}=\eta\:V_T\:\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}} {I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}}+1\right)\approx \frac{k\: T}{q}\:\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{I_\text{D}} {I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}}\right)$$

Just as you write.

Your question is about why, if this is all there is, that there the sign of the derivative of diode voltage \$V_\text{D}\$ with respect to temperature \$T\$ is negative, rather than positive.

It's a good question.

### Answer

The missing element is that the commonly found Shockley equation is short-hand. (I've been hinting about it, above, with the use of \$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}\$, earlier.)

As it turns out, the temperature dependence of \$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}\$ is huge. The approximate equation looks like this:

$$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}=I_{\text{SAT}\left(T_\text{nom}\right)}\cdot\left[\left(\frac{T}{T_\text{nom}}\right)^{3}e^{\frac{E_g}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{T_\text{nom}}-\frac{1}{T}\right)}\right]$$

\$E_g\$ is the effective energy gap (in eV) and \$k\$ is Boltzmann's constant (in appropriate units.) \$T_\text{nom}\$ is the temperature at which the equation was calibrated, of course, and \$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T_\text{nom}\right)}\$ is the extrapolated saturation current at that calibration temperature.

This formula heavily depends upon fundamental thermodynamics theory and the ***Boltzmann factor***, which you can easily look up and is above represented by the factor: \$e^{\frac{E_g}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{T_\text{nom}}-\frac{1}{T}\right)}\$. It's based on the simple ratio of the numbers of states at different temperatures; really no more complex than fair dice used in elementary probability theory. Perhaps the best introduction to the *Boltzmann factor* is C. Kittel, ***"Thermal Physics"***, John Wiley & Sons, 1969, chapters 1-6 in particular.

The power of 3 used in the equation above is actually a problem, because of the temperature dependence of diffusivity, \$\frac{k T}{q} \mu_T\$. And even that, itself, ignores the bandgap narrowing caused by heavy doping. In practice, the power of 3 is itself turned into a model parameter.

The power of 3 is approximate and is sometimes treated as an "adjustable" parameter. But close.

### Summary

Once you realize the fuller form of the Shockley equation, you are now able to work out the details about why the temperature variation is so different -- not only in magnitude, but also in sign. The thermal voltage component would normally imply a positive sign. But the \$I_{\text{SAT}\left(T\right)}\$ factor overwhelms this response and changes the sign, itself.