# How do I calculate Io and n from the Shockley equation given two operation points?

Tags: diodes, homework, math

[image: exercise]

In this exercise I'm given the Vd and Id in two operation points and I need to calculate Io and n from the Shockley equation. I've tried isolating Io and replacing it in the other equation but then I wasn't able to solve the n. Maybe I need to apply other strategy?

Comment: Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328830/how-to-measure-the-inverse-saturation-current-of-a-diode/328956#328956

Comment: Hey @G36 thank you for your answer. How do I get the nV_T equation?

Comment: First, we need to rearrange the Shockley equation to get \$V_{F}\$  And next  you need to find \$V_{F2} - V_{F1}\$. After that, you will be able to solve for \$nV_T\$

Comment: Take a look at this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502204/emitter-follower-class-a-amplifier/502218#502218 and \$ΔV_{BE}\$ equation.

Comment: @GabrielCorrales Usually need at least three. There is also a bulk resistance to pick up.